# How can group theory explain movement on a hexagonal tiling?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, infinite-groups, tessellations

(As a prelude, I have no formal math training other than high school. I am a beginner with group theory and have just recently begun picking it up and seeing its potential uses.)

Imagine an infinite game board whose spaces make a hexagonal tiling. Pieces on this board can move directly to adjacent spaces from their current space, or choose not to move at all (denoted as **e**). The six directions they can move could be called **N**, **NE**, **SE**, **S**, **SW**, and **NW**. This forms three distinct axes, where positive movement on axis **a** would correspond with **N**, positive movement on axis **b** would correspond with **SE**, and positive movement on axis **c** would correspond with **SW**.

Describing movement on this board meets the criteria of an abellian group:

- *Closure:* Any combination of movements will still land the piece on this infinite game board.
- *Associativity*: `(a • b) • c` will result in the same location as `a • (b • c)`, although they will take different paths.
- *Identity element:* The zero movement (not moving at all) combined with any other movement results in just the other movement. (`e • a = a`, `a • e = a`)
- *Inverse element:* Moving one space towards **N** and then one space towards **S** results in zero net movement. (`a • (-a) = e`)
- *Commutativity:* Moving one space on the **a** axis and then one space on the **b** axis results in the same position as moving one space on the **b** axis and then one space on the **a** axis. (`a • b = b • a`)

The ways that movements combine is interesting, though. The three axes are not orthogonal to each other. For instance, `a • b • c = e` and `a • b = -c` for *all* axes.

I'm looking for a deeper understanding of the patterns that emerge from this. Does this group have a name? How can one use group theory to describe, for instance, an algorithm that can determine if two long lists of movements on the board result in the same net movement? (`a • a • b • c • (-a) = e`)

Comment: So this group must contain more than just $e$, $\pm a$, $\pm b$, and $\pm c$, right? It must be an infinite group. Because you have to deal with questions like $a\cdot a = ?$

Comment: I think you are on the right track. Your infinite group has three _generators_ but they are not independent. You've found the _relation_ among them. You could start reading here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group . There may well be web references for your particular group.

Comment: This group is isomorphic to the set of complex numbers generated via addition/subtraction from $e=0$, $a = \exp(+i \pi/2)$, $b = \exp(-i \pi/6)$, $c = \exp(+i 7\pi/6)$. This can be used to answer your last question. Add up the complex numbers corresponding to your lists of movements and see if they come out the same.

Comment: I believe this group of translations is the same as group p6m [described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group#Group_p6mm) without the rotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Proof:

From JohnBarber's presentation in the comments above, the group is also isomorphic to the set of complex numbers generated by $a$ and $b$, defined as in his comment (since $a+b+c=0$). For $z \in G$, $z$ has a unique representation as $\lambda a + \mu b$, where $\lambda$, $\mu$ are integers (exercise: prove it's unique).

Then define a group homomorphism $\phi$ from $G$ to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ by $\phi(a) = (1, 0)$ and $\phi(b) = (0, 1)$. The homomorphism is well defined since the representation of $z$ was unique and $\phi$ is defined on the generators.

Also, the homomorphism is injective (check the kernel), and surjective (look at $ma+nb$), so it is an isomorphism.

Notice that $\phi(c) = (-1, -1)$. So, for some sequence of moves, convert $a$ to $(1,0)$, $b$ to $(0,1)$ and $c$ to $(-1, -1)$ and add the points.

Comment: This is well put-together, and it also answers my question of how to implement an efficient algorithm. I had seen coordinate systems for this type of grid which use two numbers before, but I failed to see how it would work since I was too caught up on there being _three_ axes.